# React - One scroll for Multiple Components

Tags: reactjs, scroll

I have 2 separate components that have dynamic width and overflow: hidden.

Is there a way to have one scrollbar that will scroll both of them?

Comment: put both components in another component, and use the parent component for scrolling?

Comment: Sounds so obvious. Sorry for stupid question. I am just starting my journey with programming.

Comment: no worries. Sometimes we just need to talk it out, that's why we have sites like stackoverflow.